# How to use React.memo() in a file with named exports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm used to `export default React.memo(SomeComponent);` so React can memoize my components.

But in a file where I'm using named exports. How can I use `React.memo()` ?

```
export { React.memo(MainPostTopic), React.memo(MainPostSubtopic) };
```

The line above doesn't work.

**EXAMPLE FILE**

```
function MainPostTopic(props) {
  console.log('Rendering MainPostTopic...');
  return (
    <LS.Topic_H2 id={props.id}>
      {props.value}
    </LS.Topic_H2>
  );
}

function MainPostSubtopic(props) {
  console.log('Rendering MainPostSubtopic...');
  return (
    <LS.Subtopic_H3>
      {props.value}
    </LS.Subtopic_H3>
  );
}

export { MainPostTopic, MainPostSubtopic };
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what I've ended up doing:

```
const MainPostTopic = React.memo(
  function MainPostTopic(props) {
    console.log('Rendering MainPostTopic...');
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
);

const MainPostSubtopic = React.memo(
  function MainPostSubtopic(props) {
    console.log('Rendering MainPostSubtopic...');
    return (
      ...
    );
  }
);

export { MainPostTopic, MainPostSubtopic };
```

I kept the same name for the functions and the exports.

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
export const MemoMainPostTopic = React.memo(MainPostTopic);
```

or

```
const MainPostTopic = memo(() => {
 ...
});

export { MainPostTopic };
```

Answer (score 5):

Exports that aren't `default` need to be named.

```
const MemoizedMainPostTopic = React.memo(MainPostTopic)

export { MemoizedMainPostTopic }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give name to the object properties you are exporting.

```
const MainPostTopicComponent = React.memo(MainPostTopic);
const MainPostSubtopicComponent = React.memo(MainPostSubtopic);

export {
  MainPostTopicComponent,
  MainPostSubtopicComponent 
};
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Using memo with default:

```
import { memo } from "react";
const Todos = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>My Todos</h2>
      {todos.map((todo, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{todo}</p>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(Todos);
```

Now only if the todos property changed the component will re-render